# RadioButton with WebView for displaying Maths Formula using MathJax

Tags: android, android-webview, mathjax, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I've done code to display maths formula in `TextView` with the use of following code.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                +"showMathMenu: false, "
                +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " 
                +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                +"'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
                +"styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
                +"});</script>"
                +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                +"></script>"
                +"<script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {"
                +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                // below, toMathML() rerurns literal MathML string
                +"mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;"
                +"}; getEscapedMML = function() {"
                +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                // below, toMathMLquote() applies &-escaping to MathML string input
                +"mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}"
                +"</script>"
                //+"<style type=\"text/css\">" 
                //+"@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;"  
                //+"src:url(\"file:///android_asset/shruti.ttf\");}"
                //+"body {font-family: 'MyCustomFont';}"
                //+"</style>"
                +"<p><span id='math'></span><p><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>"
                +"<script type='text/javascript'>"
                +"document.getElementById(\"math\").innerHTML='\\\\["+doubleEscapeTeX(question.getQuestion())+"\\\\]';"
                +"</script>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

Now i want to display that type of content like Maths formula or HTML Content in `RadioButton`

How can create Custom View for `RadioButton` that displays like **`WebView`** with **Radio**.

Your Help will be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: The only way is you need to have four web view behave like Radio button. Means four webview with different colour automatically identify as radio button . No need to display as the options are radio button. Else **`Choice is Yours`**..

Comment: Can you give me example for that how can i handle onClick event and Selection of any one.

Comment: I don't have any example It's just an Idea. I have made application with MATAJAX but options are simple answers(Radio buttons). you can refer my app on play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=avayaplus.android.competativeexamgeek